# NSDateFormatter return nill for some date

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
NSString * date=@"2015-06-29 14:04:41";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *gmtDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

Formatting date return nil for some date

```
for example.

if i try 2015-06-29 11:04:41 date it return value  

But if i try 2015-06-29 14:04:41 date it return nil
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HH` for 24-hour clock and `MM` for month, i.e. your format should be `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`.

Full description available [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

HTH

*Edited after @rmaddy spotted the second error, see comments.*

Comment: This is only partially correct. The month needs to be `MM`, not `mm`.

Comment: @rmaddy - mea culpa, missed that, thanks. Edited to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this date format

```
      NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

HH should in capital format.